Zbrush Workflow in Blender?
I've decided to swith from Zbrush and start sculpting in Blender instead. I do props for games and my workflow in Zbrush was:

Create a base blockout mesh in 3D software
Split hard edges into different UV islands
Import model into Zbrush
Create polygroups by UV Islands (Auto Groups With UV)
Dynamesh to give it a higher polycount
Polish features (Polish, Polish By Features), to give it a "bevel"
Sculpt details

Now I need to know how can I apporach the same workflow inside of Blender.
So far I've been able to do it but not exactly as I wanted.
The way I've been doing it is importing the fbx, giving it bevels on the hard edges, adding subd modifier, using Shift + R for the "dynamesh" function of blender. Sculpt details, etc.
However, I'd love to be able to replicate as close as I can my previous workflow. I've tried giving face sets by UV Seams but it's not working, it just creates a big face sets for the whole object, even when I have my islands ready.
Also, what would be the closest to the polish features in Blender? I've been using the mesh filter with the Smooth setup but it just softens the whole mesh and not only the edges that I'd want.
Anyways, hope to get some help with this.
Thanks,

Welcome to BSE.
This is an interesting topic, but it's mostly opinion based, perhaps BlenderArtists is a better place to post and discuss it in, Blender Stack Exchange is a question and answer site.
Read What topics can I ask about here?

If Face sets from UV doesn't work, probably you defined UV Islands without defining UV seams: to solve, set Edit mode, go to the UV editor window, select all islands, UV menu > Seams from Islands; now in scultp mode go to Face sets Menu > Initialize Face sets > by UV Seams: it should work.
For the Polishing issue, try to use Multires Modifier instead of Dinamesh when adding polycount in order to sulpt details, so you can still have access to the base mesh for selecting and masking areas of editing.
Some useful functions are:

in edit mode select menu > select sharp edges (you can define the angle)
Ctrl + and - to expand and contract the selection
in Sculpt mode, Face set from edit mode selection

I often go to edit mode, make a selection with advanced selection tecniques, hide the unselected geometry, go to sculpt mode, assign a mask to all visible geometry, back to edit mode unhide all: now in sculpt mode I have a mask that can be smoothed and used with the mesh filter or any other tool.
Hope it can help!
